# Flutter : image assets are not showing in android build

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying a simple flutter app. It is working fine on web. But on android, images can't load.

this is my pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
    - gif/
```

I have `images` and `gif` folders at root of project.

and I am loading images like this

```
child: Image(image: AssetImage("/images/abc.jpg"),
or 
child: Image(image: AssetImage("/gif/abc.gif"),
```

This works fine when I run on IDE, but on making android apk, images and gif are not showing.

In android folder, there is no assets directory as well.
I have tired  `flutter clean` and  `flutter create .`  but no luck.

Comment: You can create the assets directory manually

Comment: Try running flutter project as release flutter run --release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use like this

```
Image(image: AssetImage("images/abc.jpg")),
```

Comment: why is this solution accepted? This is the same solution the author tried and wasnt working on his part?

Comment: @ChristianX no it has a backslash in the path when he is typed

Comment: you are right, I'm blind, sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add following code to AndroidManifest.xml file located at android/app/src/main inside the manifest tag:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`